# How can I get SD card directories in Honeycomb?

Tags: android, memory, android-3.0-honeycomb, environment, sd-card

My question is pretty much as the title says: How can I get SD card directories in Honeycomb?

Quite a few Honeycomb tablets have multiple SD cards (internal and external). It's easy enough to get the directory of the internal one using the official guidelines ([`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)), but how can I get the directory of the external SD card and be sure that it's correct?

On my Acer it's called "mnt/external1", but on the Asus Eee Pad it's called `/Removable/MicroSD`. I've looked over the [Android Environment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html), but couldn't find anything.

Any ideas?

Comment: To the Android system, there is no such thing as an "SDcard" or removable storage. Therefore, you cannot reliably find a URI to hook into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but how can I get the directory of the external SD card and be sure that it's correct?

You can't, at least with current versions of the Android SDK. The OS only defines one external storage, and it is up to the device manufacturer to determine what that is. There are no standards for any additional types of card-based storage.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll have to do some "hacking" to get them then :)